# How to pass an object as an argument to the function mousePressed() in Processing

Tags: java, processing

running `println(game.gameOn)` for the function below still output `false`.

1. why this ambiguity?
2. what's the solution?

Maybe I can't pass in an object as a parameter to the function `mousePressed()`

```java
void mousePressed(Game game) {
    game.gameOn = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an object to [`mousePressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html). `mousePressed()` is an event callback and called by the system during the event handling.

The one and only possible argument to `mousePressed` is the event argument of type `MouseEvent`.e.g.:

```java
void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
   println("EVENT " + event);
}
```

If you want to access an object in `mousePressed`, then you've to use a global variable. e.g.:

```
Game game = new Game();

void mousePressed() {
   game.gameOn = false;
}
```

Comment: This. Also, there are only 2 signatures for MousePressed: the one without an overload and this one: `void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)`.

Comment: @laancelot Of course, I know. I was not finished yet.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful. Great answer btw, adding the bit about using a global variable will probably be really helpful to the OP.

Comment: @laancelot Thank's

Comment: OK then, thanks for the answer guys. I've learned a new thing